# Maven build failing on dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I have a local artefact repository which my maven settings are pointed at but for some reason this doesn't seem to hit it, and fails all the time when trying to do an install.
I can access the url directly in my browser and can also access the maven repo via browser.
I can also ping both.

Any ideas why it keeps failing?
Stack trace below

Cheers,

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -T 8C
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav/1.0-beta-2/wagon-webdav-1.0-beta-2.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project uk.co.three:Three:0.1 (/Users/***/Projects/three/Development/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:1.0-beta-2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:1.0-beta-2 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:1.0-beta-2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:pom:1.0-beta-2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Are you connected through any kind of proxy? You may have set up your browser, but not eclipse.

Comment: I havn't setup anything in exlipse except for a blank workspace. Could this be an issue? I have added my corporate proxys to my network settings and that seems fine?

Comment: What does the definition of this local repository look like in your POM file?

Comment: <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://10.41.1.132/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>

Comment: it seems it's still trying to hit repo.maven instead of my local network repo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you used the embedded or an external maven installation (Window-> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations).

If it's external you have to declare your corporate proxy in the `settings.xml` (in the conf folder of your external installation or in your local repository).

It may be also the case if you use the embedded maven. Then you have to provide a settings file in "Global settings for embedded installation".

If you are using an external maven installation you can also try the command line outside eclipse.

With

```
mvn -U ...
```

You can force maven to look for the latest plugin versions.

Comment: That's it!! Thank-you! I was trying to use an external maven, so had all my settings setup for this but it was never actually being reached, the default install of maven was being used which I didn't know actually existed. Thanks for the help, this was a pain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using proxy and you have unzipped the Maven directory, then 
update settings.xml in **{APACHE_MAVEN_DIR}\conf** like below,

just update the *"REPLACE~~"* strings with the proper info, and try again.

```
<proxies>
 <proxy>
    <id>example-proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.example.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Here is the official documentation for proxy configuration in maven settings.xml:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind the proxy, you can use

`mvn clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=<your proxy host> -DproxyPort=<port>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up your eclipse's proxy configuration in

`Settings -> General -> Network Connection`

and try again, it seems to be a matter of visibility.

Comment: Just checked, that contains my corporate proxy which seems to be ok. I agree it seems to be a matter of visibility

Comment: Try to check http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav/1.0-beta-2/wagon-webdav-1.0-beta-2.pom from eclipse's web browser. It should fail.

Comment: From eclipse web browser? I can access it ok from chrome

Comment: Try to change your eclipse proxy settings to Schema=HTTP, Host=Dynamic, Port=Dynamic, Provider=Native. It will take your browser's proxy settings (last idea)

Comment: @Rhyso yes, Eclipse has its own web browser, try to check from it, if it doesn't work, change what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running the below command from withing your project,

```
$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```